# React Native: iOS Auto inserting text into TextInput scroll to bottom

Tags: ios, react-native, scroll, textinput

Below is my setup for auto inserting text into a TextInput with a **fixed height**.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { myText: 'abc' }

  _onPress = () => {
    this.setState({ myText: this.state.myText + '\n 1' });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 65, backgroundColor: 'red' }}
          multiline={true}
          value={this.state.myText}
        />
        <Button
          onPress={this._onPress}
          title="Add text"
          color="#841584"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Basically I want to add text on my button click, and get the textInput scroll to the bottom as new text keeps on getting added. But this doesnt seem to be the case right now. This is how it looks.

[image]

How can I make my TextInput scroll, without adding any keyboard interaction to it ?

I am using ReactNative version `v0.53.3`

Comment: TexInput is scrolling what you mention https://snack.expo.io/Bkz3PrAkX

Comment: The picture above is from my iOS emulator. Do you see the text getting cutoff ?

Comment: Seems it works on Android but not on iOS. Just tried your snack on both and I see the difference.

Comment: Yes it is not work on IOS.

Comment: for me it works fine.